# Performing mathematical calculation of two list of list

Tags: python, list

I have two list of list containing:

```
L1 = [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]]
L2 = [[3.1,3.2],[3.3,3.4],[3.5,3.6]]
```

and i want to write a python program to extract each list from L1 to be compared with L2 and performing perhaps something like multiplication?

Example: a case where python takes [2.1,2.2] from L1 and compare with [3.1,3.2] and perform multiplication.

I've tried but it seemed like i am not doing it right. Note: **multiplicationL** is a function defined and it **takes two lists** as **parameters**.

```
L1 = [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]]
L2 = [[3.1,3.2],[3.3,3.4],[3.5,3.6]]

for i in L1:
    for j in L2:
         result = multiplicationL(L1[i],L2[j])
print(result)
```

Frankly, i want to take one list from L1 and one list from L2 and perform operations on them.

Comment: here `i,j` will be the elements of `L1,L2` not indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiplication, This will do the job:

```
L1 = [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]]
L2 = [[3.1,3.2],[3.3,3.4],[3.5,3.6]]

result=[]
for i in L1:
    for j in L2:
         res = [i[a]*j[a] for a in range(len(i))]
         result.append(res)
print(result)
```

In order to generalize it to other operations, you can define the operation in a separate function, as follows:

```
L1 = [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]]
L2 = [[3.1,3.2],[3.3,3.4],[3.5,3.6]]

def multiply(i,j):
    return [i[a]*j[a] for a in range(len(i))]

result=[]
for i in L1:
    for j in L2:
         res = multiply(i,j)
         result.append(res)
print(result)
```

This prints

```
[[6.510000000000001, 7.040000000000001], [6.93, 7.48], [7.3500000000000005, 7.920000000000001], [7.13, 7.68], [7.589999999999999, 8.16], [8.049999999999999, 8.64], [7.75, 8.32], [8.25, 8.84], [8.75, 9.360000000000001]]
```

Comment: Thanks it helped! But i want to ask something regarding the early stage of the process. You see, L1 has [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]] and L2 has [[3.1,3.2],[3.3,3.4],[3.5,3.6]] . Would it be possible if i create a temp list to contain one list at a time from L1 and L2 to be passed onto the defined function? Example: tempL1 = [2.1,2.2] and tempL2 = [3.1,3.2] then these two list goes into the defined function where two lists are it's parameter.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what happened in res = multiply(i,j). i iterates over the 3 elements in  L1. These elements are lists, so each time i is a list. Similarly, j iterates over the 3 lists in L2. So in the first time the function reaches the row res = multiply(i,j), we have i=[2.1,2.2] and j=[3.1,3.2], and thus the first res is multiply([2.1,2.2],[3.1,3.2]).

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

L1 = [[2.1,2.2],[2.3,2.4],[2.5,2.6]]
L2 = [[3.1,3.2],[3.3,3.4],[3.5,3.6]]

for i in L1:
    for j in L2:
        print(np.dot(i,j))
   ...:         

13.55
14.41
15.27
14.81
15.75
16.69
16.07
17.09
18.11
```